# VB.NET - How do I search through Webpage source for particular div and output inside txt as msgbox?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, forms, visual-studio

VB.NET - How do I search through Webpage source for particular div and output inside txt as msgbox?

So far I can download a webpage's source code. But I don't know how to search through it for a particular string of information.

Code so far:

```
Dim source As String = New 
System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString("http://pagewantingtouse.com")
```

The division is called "description", I'm after the information within it. I want to output it as a message-box.

Example below:

```
<div class="description">       
 The Amazing Spider-Man is a 2012 American superhero film based on the Marvel
 Comics character Spider-Man. It is the fourth installment of the Spider-Man film series, serving
 as a reboot.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this laying around from a project I did. It takes the page and stream reads it into a web browser, and then pulls out whatever you want from it.  I looked at reading a string before, problem was for me, at least, that you had to find the length between the tags, etc.  This worked well for me:

```
 Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("http://pagewantingtouse.com") 'create a web request to the html file
    Using response As WebResponse = request.GetResponse() 'get the response back from the request
        Using Reader As New StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream) 'identify how you want to read the response and assign it to streamreader
            Dim webtext As String = Reader.ReadToEnd() 'read the response (web page) as a string to the end of the file

 Dim wbc As WebBrowser = New WebBrowser() 'create a web browser to handle the data. this will help sift through it

            wbc.DocumentText = ""

            With wbc.Document
                .OpenNew(True)
                .Write(webtext) 'write the web page response into the web browser control


                Dim itemlist As HtmlElementCollection = .GetElementsByTagName("DIV")

                    For Each item In itemlist 'look at each item in the collection
                    If item.classname = "description" Then 
                        msgbox item.innertext 'this would msgbox your description
                    Exit For 'exit once found
                    End If



                Next 'do this for every item in the collection until we find it

            End With 

        wbc.dispose()

        End Using

    End Using
```

if you want to tell me the page, I can update the code, but this should at least help answer your question.

Comment: Edited the loop to IF THEN .classname instead of .class.  It appears however, the web page isn't returning the description at all, because there is a browser detection scheme, and its saying the browser is unsupported, when using both webrequest and webclient.download to get the string of the page.  Perhaps someone can shed light on this workaround.  The thing that comes to mind is possibly splitting out that javascript that detects and stops the browser.